# Problem with ON SCREEN KEYBOARD (ONBOARD) on Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)

Tags: onscreen-keyboard, onboard

How to use `onboard` onscreen keyboard on Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)?

Up to Ubuntu 20.04 everything worked fine but with Ubuntu 21.04 when the application `onboard` has been launched the screen sharing is incorrectly enabled ...

Does anyone know the alternative option for `onboard` application?

Comment: See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421888/onboard-keyboard-not-working-in-22-04)