# Onboard Keyboard not working in 22.04

Tags: keyboard, onboard

Since installing 22.04 a month ago the Onboard Keyboard app has stopped working. This is the very useful onscreen keyboard that lets you enter keystrokes via mouse clicks.  Entering sensitive data this way offered a degree of protection against keylogging malware or hackers.  With Onboard no longer working, that layer of security is no longer available.

This is evidently a bug of some kind.  Does anyone know if it has been recognised as such and whether a fix is in the pipeline?

I should add that although I am familiar with basic Linux commands and using the Terminal, I am not Linux fluent.  So answers in plain English please!

Comment: What do you mean it "stopped working". What are the exact actions that you take? What is the expected result? And what actually happens? Please be specific.

Comment: Hi Nmath.  After installing 22.04, when I clicked on Onboard nothing happened. I had to click a second time to get it to launch.  When I tried to use it, to enter a password on a website for example, nothing came out.  Worse, if I opened the Ubuntu Software app, Onboard was automatically launched if you clicked on the little magnifying glass search facility.  But instead of just sitting there on the screen, it kept disappearing and reappearing.  This was so odd that I have now uninstalled both Onboard and Onboard settings.  The search facility within Ubuntu Software now works normally.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug reported 2017-03-13, that Onboard does not work with Wayland. See the following bug report at Launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/onboard/+bug/1672465

I suggest that you try again after switching to the classic Xorg instead of Wayland. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857) shows a way to switch in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. (Onboard works for me in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with Xorg.)

---

Edit: If you want to keep using Wayland, you can try the following alternative:

- Activate the built-in keyboard (previously Caribou)

  You can do it separately on the log in screen for the log in screen and via

  ```
  gnome-control-center
  ```

  - Accessibility - Typing - Screen keyboard

  for the desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the fact that OnBoard does not work, I tried the sudo apt update, followed by sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and got the result "All the available drivers are already installed". So OnBoard still does not work in my 22.04.
Please, are there any other suggestions.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1254328)